# ASP.NET MVC 4 Cross field or property validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to figure out how to validate that a user has entered matching passwords when they sign up.  Is there anything built in to MVC 4 Data Annotations that I can use for this or is the only route creating a custom validation attribute?

If I do have to create a custom validation attribute, how do I access the password property (assuming I put the annotation on the confirm password property)?  Also, are there any commonly used libraries for this type of validation?

This is what I have for the beginning of a custom validation attribute, just not sure how to access the password property:

```
public class CrossFieldValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value) //how do I get the other value in here?
    {
        //validation logic here
        return base.IsValid(value);
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: matching passwords with the database or matching passwords while creating their login account? (thus signing up)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom attributes and set additional information to their public properties.

```
public class CustomValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string MeaningfulValidationInfo { get; set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // do whatever meaningful with MeaningfulValidationInfo 
        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }
}
```

You'd set the additional info this way:

```
[CustomValidationAttribute(MeaningfulValidationInfo = "blah")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

If you are trying to check if both entered passwords were identical, you can simply validate that in your model.

```
    public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Compare("Password")]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

There is already a comparison validation attribute built into mvc. See the documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.compareattribute(v=vs.98).aspx

An example of use would be:

```
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Uh oh")]
    public string PasswordAgain { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare annotation is the easiest option for this. As you can see below, `Compare` points to the `Password` attribute.

```
[Required]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use the **Compare Validate ** control inbuilt on the ASP.NET Tools

I've provided a sample below

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <asp:Label
        id="lblBirthDate"
        Text="Birth Date:"
        AssociatedControlID="txtBirthDate"
        Runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox
        id="txtBirthDate"
        Runat="server" />
    <asp:CompareValidator
        id="cmpBirthDate"
        Text="(Invalid Date)"
        ControlToValidate="txtBirthDate"
        Type="Date"
        Operator="DataTypeCheck"
        Runat="server" />

    <br /><br />

    <asp:Button
        id="btnSubmit"
        Text="Submit"
        Runat="server" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Please refer to any of the links below to widen your knowledge

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0160__Validation/CompareValidatorperformsthreedifferenttypesofvalidations.htm

http://www.vkinfotek.com/aspnetvalidationcontrols.html