# Data Validation with an Entity's Property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

I am creating a small auction Site with ASP.NET MVC. I am extremely new to ASP and am not sure how all the functionality works. The part of the auction that I am working on is bidding on the current item. Right now I have simple validation in my (Bid) model as followed:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a maximum bid")]
    [Range(0, double.PositiveInfinity)]
    public decimal MaxBid { get; set; }
```

When a user wants to make a bid, they are given a form through the "Create" view where they enter their max bid. What I have simply verifies on the fly that they actually enter a value and that it is non-negative.

> However, more accurately they have to enter a value higher than the specific item.Bid.CurBid value.
>
> Is there a way to validate like the above validation where it won't let the user actually create a bid and gives an error message instantly?

Thank you for any and all help.

**Edit:**
So in my Create method in my BidsController I have added the following code:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "BidId,ItemId,BidderId,MaxBid,CurBid,BidDate,BidStatusId")] Bid bid, Guid itemId, string usrId)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Item item = db.Items.Find(itemId);
            Bid activeBid = db.Bids.Find(item.ActiveBidId);

            if(bid.MaxBid < activeBid.CurBid)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Your maximum bid must be greater than the current bid.");
                return RedirectToAction("Create", "Bids", new {itemId, usrId});
            }
```

> I attempted to add this model error so that it would display like the other errors on my "Create" Bid view. However, the error is not showing up. Is this because I am not returning a bid model, but instead Redirecting to the "Create" view page?

Code for my "Create" View:

```
<h4>Bid</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MaxBid, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MaxBid, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MaxBid, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I thought the validation summary would display my error message.

Comment: Personally, data annotations can work well for single field validation.  Cross-field and cross-entity validations just are not addressed by data annotations.

Comment: For cross-field validations, you can add a method IsValid() to the entity that returns a bool, or a message, or an object or an exception (whatever) that basically indicates are the cross-field validations successful and give you the information to log and/or notify the user in the UI.

Comment: For cross-entity, it is situational based upon where the validation is performed (Client/Server), what information is available at that point, is Unit of Work pattern being followed (multi-entity), yada yada.

Comment: @JohnWhite has the right of it, but to be clear, you will need to do the validation again at the business layer in case the client has been tricked or spoofed in some way, or in case the situation changes between the user submitting the request and your business layer processing it. Any validation on the UI is purely for the purpose of giving the user immediate feedback.

Comment: @SomeGuy Immediate feedback is really what I was going for. I read about creating a class that inherits from the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute class in order to create custom validation data annotations. However, you're saying this can't be done because I am dealing with cross-field validation?

Comment: @C.Math This thread gives you a pretty good idea of your options for cross-field validation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465491/asp-net-mvc-4-cross-field-or-property-validation

Comment: No, you *can* but it causes a chicken and egg problem.  Which field gets updated in what order.  You don't want to introduce dependencies like that.  What @SomeGuy was mentioning is a related topic in which validations should be addressed in Client (for speed) but also Server-side (for security/data integrity).

Comment: I have edited my post to show what I have added. This is in my business logic (BidsController). Is this the best way to accomplish what I am trying to do? @JohnWhite

Comment: Use a conditional validation attribute, for example a [foolproof](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof) `[GreaterThan("CurBid")]` attribute applied to your `MaxBid` property to give both client and server side validation (not the `[Range]` attribute is not required). And if you want to learn to write your own, refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: And note with your current code, you need to return the view when you add a `ModelStateError` (so the error message is displayed), not redirect

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you. How to I use the foolproof [GreaterThan("CurBid")] attribute in my project?

Comment: Yes, I thought that might be the case, however I can't return a view in this context. I think a conditional validation attribute is my best option, I am just not sure how to implement it.

Comment: [Cross-posted to Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/195115/52915)

Comment: @Mast difference is I was posting on here specifically about Data Validation and the Code Review was to actually review my code/method for improvements. No need to downvote.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I simply just am not grasping how to get the specific CurBid of the activeBid and use that in conditional validation like anything I've read. I only see it on the Model class and I am not sure how to retrieve the current bid on runtime (server side) to validate it. I feel like this shouldn't be that complicated but I can't wrap my head around it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, final validation should be done at the business layer rather than on the viewmodel. This is important for any number of reasons, but perhaps the most critical at this stage in your architecture is that it will help you keep your code organized. A trip to the business layer for such a small amount of information will be fractions of a second in any reasonable scenario anyways.

Once you're there, your validation is pretty straightforward. Assuming you have some double `m` which represents the highest bid so far, and some double `n` representing the current bid, you simply need to check that `n > m`. If it isn't, you can go kick back a rejection message to the UI. Notably, this should not be an exception: The user is giving you input which you do expect to occasionally receive and know exactly how to handle. Simply produce a message informing the user that their bid is lower than `m`, and is therefore invalid, and allow them to enter a new bid if they so choose.

After you've put your back-end validation in place, you're free to circle back to the front-end and write preliminary validation logic there. This validation will not be foolproof and often won't even contain a full set of validation steps. The goal is to make sure your front-end validation remains lightweight while still catching most errors. In this particular case, that likely means running your checks on a cached value of the last bid, as well as performing basic validation steps for payment, such as [Luhn Algorithm checks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) against credit card info.

Comment: True, but simple validations can (should?) be replicated Client-side (even cross-field) to reduce round trips (important for scalability).  Just an opinion.

Comment: I have edited my post to show what I have added. This is in my business logic (BidsController). Is this the best way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: @C.Math That seems like a fine way to go about it to me. Remember that your ActionResult can be used to inform the front-end about whether or not their bid was successful, and how they can proceed from there.

Comment: I edited my post again. I tried to instead inform my view of an error message to display, however it is not showing up.

Comment: _rather than on the viewmodel_?? What poor advice. It should definitely be done on the view model so the UI gives immediate feedback (without posting the form)

Comment: @StephenMuecke We get into the distinction there in the comments above. Ideally, you have validation on the client for responsiveness, but you always need validation on the back-end. You are correct that my answer should be more thorough in its description.

Comment: Updated the answer for completeness' sake.